# How to scrape this website items where the lazy load pauses with each scroll before loading the items?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

Hi I am trying to scrape this site products name and units by using the search function in the website from a list of words.

I tried using the scroll method however there's a pause for every scroll down, how do I handle this? As I am scraping  a lot of the pages, what's the best way to handle the scroll? I tried using a headless chrome, however it's not possible , so here's a chromedrivermanager that opens the window and scroll.
The website is this https://www.sayurbox.com/

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options



def selenium(soup):

  driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install() )
  driver.maximize_window()
  driver.get(url)
  driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
  time.sleep(3)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
  driver.close()

#scraping components
list=['ayam', 'sabun','sayur', 'common']
for item in list:
    URL= "https://www.sayurbox.com"
    itemsEncoded = str(item).replace(" ", "%20")
    url = f"{URL}/products/s/{itemsEncoded}"
    print(f"{url} start scraping")
    soup = selenium(url)

    #handling for items not found
    try:
        found = soup.find_all("span", {"class" : "NotFoundMessage__container__title"})
        if found[0].text == "Produk tidak ditemukan.":
            print('url not found')
    #if found continue scraping
    except:  
      #scrape details
      #get product title
      productTitle = soup.find_all('span', {"class":"ProductItem__container__name"})
      product=[]
      for p in productTitle:
         p = p.text
         product.append(p)   
      #get unit
      units= soup.find_all('span', {"class":"Product__container__priceWrapper__packDesc"})
      unit =[]
      for u in units:
         u = u.text
         unit.append(u)

     #write into dataframe
     data = {'product':product,
    'unit':unit,
    'date':datetime.date(datetime.now())
    }
```

The above code can only scroll 1 time, however there are still items beneath the 1st scroll.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: How to scroll all the way to the bottom of the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to use Selenium. You get the data through a POST and just change the page parameter to get more. Essentially thats what happens when you scroll. And then just change the `'value'` parameter to go through your list as well.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd


url = 'https://api.sayurbox.io/graphql'
headers = {
    'authorization': 'eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImY4NDY2MjEyMTQxMjQ4NzUxOWJiZjhlYWQ4ZGZiYjM3ODYwMjk5ZDciLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJhbm9ueW1vdXMiOnRydWUsImF1ZCI6InNheXVyYm94LWF1ZGllbmNlIiwiYXV0aF90aW1lIjoxNjUwNTUxMDYxLCJleHAiOjE2NTMxNDMwNjEsImlhdCI6MTY1MDU1MTA2MSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuc2F5dXJib3guY29tIiwibWV0YWRhdGEiOnsiZGV2aWNlX2luZm8iOm51bGx9LCJuYW1lIjpudWxsLCJwaWN0dXJlIjpudWxsLCJwcm92aWRlcl9pZCI6ImFub255bW91cyIsInNpZCI6IjFjNDE1ODFiLWQzMjItNDFhZi1hOWE5LWE4YTQ4OTZkODMxZiIsInN1YiI6InFSWXF2OFV2bEFucVR3NlE1NGhfbHdTNFBvTk8iLCJ1c2VyX2lkIjoicVJZcXY4VXZsQW5xVHc2UTU0aF9sd1M0UG9OTyJ9.MSmOz0mAe3UjhH9KSRp-fCk65tkTUPlxiJrRHweDEY2vqBSnUP43TO8ug3P38x8igxC4qguCOlwCTCPfUEWFhr3X8ePY7u7I7D22tV1LOF7Tm6T8PuLzHbmlBTgPK9C_GJpXwLAKnD2A535r-9DttYGt4QytIeWua8NKyW_riURfWGnhZBBMjEPeVPJBqGn1jMtZoh_iUeRb-kWccJ8IhBDQr0T1Op6IDMJuw3x6uf1Ks_SVqEVA0ZGIM1GVwuyZ87JYT4kqITNgi6yNy69jVH6gDFqBkTwJ7ZNWj8NCQsaRfh03bZROZzY9MeCtL6if_8D9newYZagyZu5mKTJNzg',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.88 Safari/537.36'}

rows = []
for page in range(1,10):
    print(page)
    payload = {
        'operationName': "getCatalogVariant",
        'query': "query getCatalogVariant($deliveryDate: String!, $deliveryArea: String!, $deliveryCode: String, $limit: Int!, $page: Int!, $type: CatalogType, $value: String) {\n  catalogVariantList(deliveryDate: $deliveryDate, deliveryArea: $deliveryArea, deliveryCode: $deliveryCode, limit: $limit, page: $page, type: $type, value: $value) {\n    limit\n    page\n    size\n    hasNextPage\n    category {\n      displayName\n    }\n    list {\n      key\n      availability\n      categories\n      farmers {\n        image\n        name\n      }\n      image {\n        md\n        sm\n        lg\n      }\n      isDiscount\n      discount\n      labelDesc\n      labelName\n      maxQty\n      name\n      displayName\n      nextAvailableDates\n      packDesc\n      packNote\n      price\n      priceFormatted\n      actualPrice\n      actualPriceFormatted\n      shortDesc\n      stockAvailable\n      type\n      emptyMessageHtml\n      promoMessageHtml\n    }\n  }\n}\n",
        'variables': {
            'deliveryArea': "Jabodetabek",
            'deliveryCode': "JK01",
            'deliveryDate': "Friday, 22 April 2022",
            'limit': 12,
            'page': page,
            'type': "SEARCH",
            'value': "ayam"}}
    
    jsonData = requests.post(url, headers = headers, json=payload).json()
    items = jsonData['data']['catalogVariantList']['list']
    
    rows += items
    
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
                                                   key  ...     promoMessageHtml
0                    Sreeya Sayap Ayam Frozen 500 gram  ...                 None
1                               SunOne Kulit Ayam 1 kg  ...                 None
2                         Bundling Ayam & Pisau 1 pack  ...   Promo!! maksimal 5
3                                SunOne Hati Ayam 1 kg  ...     Hanya tersedia 1
4                  Wellfed Daging Ayam Giling 250 gram  ...                 None
..                                                 ...  ...                  ...
103                Frozchick Ayam Bumbu Kecap 400 gram  ...     Hanya tersedia 5
104      Sasa Larasa Bumbu Ungkep Ayam Kalasan 33 gram  ...   Promo!! maksimal 5
105    Bundling Indomie Kuah Ayam Bawang 69 gram 5 pcs  ...   Promo!! maksimal 7
106                    Bundling MPASI Dada Ayam 1 pack  ...  Promo!! maksimal 10
107  Berkah Chicken Paha Bawah Probiotik Organik 55...  ...  Promo!! maksimal 10

[108 rows x 24 columns]
```

Comment: Hi this works but after 3 items nothing is being returned even though there's an item. Tried to rotate user agent and put sleep(2) still to no avail.

Comment: Ok. I’ll look into it. Might just need to create a session.

Comment: Thank you. found the payload in the network too. thank your for teaching me something new.

Comment: Not sure what your issue is. Works completely fine on my end. I would just make sure your user agent in your Dev Tool headers,